# Getting a JSON out of a mongoDB document

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

Working with python 2.7, pymongo, mongoDB 2.6.1:

I have a mongoDB collection.

Now I'm trying to take a few field from it and make a list of JSONs of it into a file (that's the input the other side expects).

I tried the following code:

```
my_file = open("test.csv", "w")
for doc in collection.find():
    json.dumps({"command": doc["command"], "data": doc["data"]}, my_file)
```

and got the error:
    KeyError: 'command'

What am I missing here?

Comment: does all the document in the collection have `command`? try using `doc.get('command')`

Answer (score 1):

It means the at least one record does not have `command` field. Check the records have `command` fields.

In addition to that, [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) takes only one positional argument, unlike [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) which takes an object and a file object.

And if you dump records into one file, it would be hard to decode it back. You'd better to dump a list object that contains the record.

```
with open("test.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(list(collection.find()), f)
```

To get back the records:

```
with open("test.json") as f:
    records = json.load(f)
```

Comment: I did not have the "command" field on all records. Anyway, I tried this (picking the selected fields), and got a file with "[]" in it. That's all.

Comment: @mudahan, If you print it (`print(list(collection.find()))`), what do you see?

Comment: I see all the data inside. So how come it dosn't work when I put it in a file?

Comment: @mudahan, Try this: `f.write(json.dumps(list(collection.find())))`. If this does not work let me know what this print: `print(json.dumps(list(collection.find())))`

Comment: The f.write() had the same output has before: [] , and so did the  print.

Comment: @mudahan, Please try this: `f.write(json.dumps([dict(x) for x in collection.find()]))`

Comment: Still the same... I managed a workaround (with many f.write("{") and such), but still looking for a "clean" answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @mudahan, How about this? http://pastebin.com/ynqKf5RN (I test it with test_collection: http://pastebin.com/UL8SRk6z )